# @RestController("/xxx") mapping is ignored

Tags: java, spring

I'am trying to create a simple, annotation based rest service which have two distinct endpoints with endpoints specified by value of @RestController annotations.
The problem is that the url provided in those annotations are ignored.

```
@RestController("/books")
public class BooksApi {

@RequestMapping("/getBook")
public String getBook() {
    return "book";
}

@RestController("/movies")
public class MoviesApi {

@RequestMapping("/getMovie")
public String getMovie() {
    return "movie";
}

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "application.webservices.apis")
public class ApiConfiguration {
}

public class ApisServletDispacher extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {ApiConfiguration.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[0];
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] {"/"};
}
}
```

So far the working url is:
http://localhost:8080/getBook
and I would like to have it changed to:
http://localhost:8080/books/getBook

I'm running on wildfly 10, to war packaged application.

Why is xxx mapping in @RestController("XXX") ignored ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BooksApi {...
```

Comment: It is working now, thanks a lot, I could not think that this value in @RequestMapping is for specifying componentname, not the path.